# ComboBox.ObjectCollection property for a user control?

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, user-controls, combobox

I have a user control with a combobox, and so I can edit its text as a property, I have the following code:

```
public ComboBox.ObjectCollection _OptionList {
    get {
        return OptionChoice.Items;
    }
    set {
        for (int i = 0; i < value.Count; i++)
        {
            OptionChoice.Items.Add(value[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

is it possible to access this property of a combobox as a property of a user control? If so what am I doing wrong? It builds and runs, but when i click on the property in VS and add a item, the new item is System.Object and won't let me change it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I read it, you merely want the same Items collection on your UserControl - acting as a pass-through for a specific combo box on the UserControl.

So tell the designer what type of list you expect it to be:

```
[Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ListControlStringCollectionEditor, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
    typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public ComboBox.ObjectCollection Items
{
    get{ return this.comboBox1.Items; }
}
```

You don't ever want a setter on a collection property.  (Well, almost never).

Comment: but i need to be able to change the items in the combobox, will this let me change it?

Comment: Yes. It works *exactly* as the original ComboBox one does because this is almost exactly the same code. Give it a try.